# Possible memory leak in basemap

Tags: python, memory-leaks, matplotlib-basemap

Consider the following Python program:

```
import sys
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

for i in range(1):
    pp=PdfPages('test.pdf')
    pindex=0
    pages=10
    rows=6
    cols=3
    for p in range(pages):      # for each page
        fig=plt.figure(figsize=[8.5, 11])   # letter size
        plt.axis('off')
        for r in range(rows):       # for each row
            for c in range(cols):       # for each column
                fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, 1+c+r*cols)
                map=Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='c')
                map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.25)
                map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30), linewidth=.25)
                map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180, 30), linewidth=.25)
        pp.savefig()
        pindex=pindex+1
    pp.close()
print 'done'
sys.stdin.readline()
```

What this simple program does is create a PDF file with 10 pages, and in each page an array of map plots (6x3). When I run this program, memory usage reaches several gigabytes by the time the program prints 'done', even though the actual file generated is but a fraction of that. When commenting out the calls to drawparallels and drawmeridians memory usage is much lower. If instead I change the range of the main loop from 1 to 5 (basically repeats the creation of the same file 5 times) then memory usage reaches tens of gigabytes, which seems to me clearly indicative of some kind of memory leak. Is this the case, and if so -- is there a way around it (apart from just not having meridians and parallels)?

Thanks!

Comment: This should really be reported on github as a possible bug, not on stackexchange.